# How do I have 2 or more radio buttons for each row of data in a table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I have 2 or more radio buttons for each row of data in a table?

This is the code I have..

```html
echo '<table>
<tr>
<td>Home</td>
<td>Not Home</td>
<td>Address</td>
<td>Suburb</td>
<td>Go</td>
<td>lat</td>
<td>lng</td>
<td>Day</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>';
$sql = "SELECT id, address, suburb, lat, lng, day, date, time FROM addresses";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


      echo '<tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="home" value="1"/></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="home" value="1"/></td>
      <td>'. $row["address"].'</td>
      <td>'. $row["suburb"].'</td>
      <td><button type="button">Go</button></td>
      <td>'. $row["lat"].'</td>
      <td>'. $row["lng"].'</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="day" disabled="true"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="date" disabled="true"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="time" disabled="true"/></td>


    </tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</table>';
```

I think I have to give each row of radio buttons a different name but how do I do that so that for each row of data that is fetched from my database will also output radio buttons relevant to that row only?

Please help. I've tried all kinds of different things but getting no where.

Comment: If you only have two values to choose from (true/false) you could use a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your radio input name must be unique for each row.

You can use id to make the radio input name unique,

> name="home['. $row["id"].']"

Try below code.

```
echo '<tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" value="1"/></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" value="0"/></td>
      <td>'. $row["address"].'</td>
      <td>'. $row["suburb"].'</td>
      <td><button type="button">Go</button></td>
      <td>'. $row["lat"].'</td>
      <td>'. $row["lng"].'</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="day" disabled="true"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="date" disabled="true"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="time" disabled="true"/></td>


    </tr>';
```

Comment: what's the meaning of diff radio buttons if the `value="1"` are same for both radio buttons?

Comment: I did not notice the value, @prakashtank thanks for that.

Comment: @AnthonyTruong, Please mark this as the answer and also give a upvote ;-)

Comment: @PraneethNidarshan. Done! Still can't upvote though. Need reputation points. hehe. Thanks again